# Missing contact after Google account sync

Tags: android, contacts

I have 2 Android phones: Samsung Note 2 &  Motorola Moto G. I use the same Google account to sync contacts between both phones. 
But recently new contacts that I add on both phones are deleted son after Google sync contacts. 
It didn't happen when I turned off contact sync. 
Is there any solution for this problem?